# Django SuspiciousFileOpretation at /admin/

Tags: python, django

I know many people asked this question. I have two laptops, one uses python 3.7 another one uses python 3.6. The code is the same, the second laptop raises this error.

here is my file in admin:

```
admin.site.register(File)
```

in models

```
class File(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField()
```

settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

any idea why I get this error when using python 3.6?

Comment: What versions of django installed on two systems?

Comment: Django 2.1.5 for both

Comment: It seems that File is inbuilt class in django 2.1.5, it's better that you rename your `File` model to something else and try.

Comment: I ve already tried that, the same(